# tinymce con plugin responsive-filemanager, no muestra imagen

Tags: javascript, php, tinymce

He instalado el filemanager al editor tinymce. El complemento funciona bien, sube archivos desde local y los guarda, crea directorios etc.

El problema es que cuando selecciono una imagen para insertarlo en el editor, no lo hace correctamente. De hecho no copia la dirección correcta de la imagen. Estos son las configuraciones y directorios que tengo:

Directorios:

```
-Editor
  +ejemplo.html
  -js
   |---tinymce
       |---------filemanager
       |---------source
       |---------thumbs
       |---------plugins
                  |--------responsivefilemanager
                  |                       |----plugin.min.js
                  |--- etc..
```

config.php:

```
'base_url' => // por defecto, no tocar.
'upload_dir' => '/source/'
'current_path' => '../source/'
'thumbs_base_path' => '../thumbs/'
```

HTML y tinymce (js):

```
plugins: [ 'responsivefilemanager' ], // etc...
external_filemanager_path:"http://localhost/editor/js/tinymce/filemanager/",
filemanager_title:"Menejador de Archivos" ,
external_plugins: { "filemanager" : "http://localhost/editor/js/tinymce/filemanager/plugin.min.js"}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

resulto, era un detalle tonto, estaban ciertamente mal redireccionadas las URL, faltaba incluir el directorio principal, /editor/ en la configuracion php